# Replace multiple occurrences of the same String separately

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make replacements to the results of re.findall in sequential order. However, in the example there are multiple occurrences of the same string. For example:

```
text = "SOME TEXT, monday-friday, MORE TEXT, thursday, MORE TEXT, monday-friday'
regex = re.compile(REGEX,re.I)
possiblereplacements = regex.findall(text)
```

The results are:

```
'monday-friday','thursday','monday-friday'
```

I then need to make a substitution for each element in the list separately. For example:

```
for item in possiblereplacements:
    text = re.sub(item,item+' 11:00-17:00',text)
```

However this replaces all instances so eventually you wind up with:

```
 text = "SOME TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, thursday 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00 11:00-17:00'
```

How can I adjust this to get my desired result which is:

```
 text = "SOME TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, thursday 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00'
```

Comment: What is `REGEX` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `re.findall`, use `re.finditer`.  Rather than a plain list of strings like you have now, it will give you a sequence of `MatchObject`s which contain the start index of each match.  Then you know exactly where to perform the replacements.

A fancier way to do it is with `re.sub`, where the replacement "string" can actually be a callback function.  The function will be called once for each match, so you can append the text you want.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with a single replacement? You don't need to use `re.findall` function here. Just put your regex inside a capturing group and replace all the matched characters with the chars inside group index 1 plus the string you want to concat with.

```
re.sub(r'(regex)', r'\1 11:00-17:00', text)
```

Example:

```
>>> text = "SOME TEXT, monday-friday, MORE TEXT, thursday, MORE TEXT, monday-friday"
>>> re.sub(r'(?i)([^,]*day[^,]*)', r'\1 11:00-17:00', text)
'SOME TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, thursday 11:00-17:00, MORE TEXT, monday-friday 11:00-17:00'
```

Comment: This helped. `(?i)(<regex pattern>)`